# JDK7 SSL conenction Issue Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

Tags: ssl, java-7

I am making a SSL connection (as client) and according to [this Oracle article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) the following two cypher suits are supported in JDK7 if you use TLSv1.2 and enable the Strong version of the jurisdiction policy.

- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

However the two cypher algorithms are ignored when making secure connection.

```
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
**Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384**
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
**Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256**
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1496192143 bytes = { 166, 200, 78, 178, 69, 10, 17, 174, 212, 142, 188, 108, 136, 152, 242, 222, 94, 231, 4, 86, 2, 99, 202, 4, 204, 130, 236, 120 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: api.sms.optus.com.au]
***
main, WRITE: **TLSv1.2** Handshake, length = 222
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
ERROR [main] (TestRest.java:42) - Error :
```

I have set the TLSv1.2

- -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

I have installed the "**JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files**" and I can confirm its successfully installed by running the following code

```
try {
    int maxAllowedKeyLength = Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES");
    System.out.println("AES: " + maxAllowedKeyLength);
    return maxAllowedKeyLength >= 256;
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    return false;
}
```

I think the two cypher algorithms are not supported in JDK7 but mistakenly mentioned in the Oracle article?

Notes:

- There is no problem if I run the c0ode in JDK8.
- I am behind firewal and had to setup proxy. but I dont think its related as I can connect in JDK8 with no issue.

Comment: There are plenty of cipher suites. Why are these particular two a problem?

Comment: @EJP Unfortunately the host accept only four cipher suits. Two of them are completely unsupported in JDK7 and the other two are the one I mention in the post. [checkhere](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.sms.optus.com.au)

Comment: Hmm, well I confirm your results, doesn't work for me either in JDK 1.7.0_25, does in 1.8.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The initial setting of the 'enabled' ciphers list is computed in `SSLContextImpl.init` before any tailoring is done, and in Java7 client the initial protocol list is only SSLv3 and TLSv1 (and in recent versions java.security configures `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` to remove SSLv3 because of POODLE) so this disables all TLSv1.2-only ciphers, which are the only ones this server will agree to. This is the source of the `Ignoring unsupported` messages in your trace before the actual handshake starts.

If using `HttpsURLConnection` you need to set *both* `https.protocols` and `https.cipherSuites` (note capital S) sysprops. If directly using `SSLSocket` you need to call both `.setEnabledProtocols` including (at least) `TLSv1.2` and `.setEnabledCipherSuites` including (at least) one of the ciphersuites you highlighted in your Q, or substitute/wrap the factory to do the equivalent.

Java8 does not have the problem because its default protocol list for both client and server is SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2, again with SSLv3 removed by `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`

Update: for 8u261 (in 2020) up, TLSv1.3 is also implemented and included in the default protocol list, and for 8u291 (in 2021) up, jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms also removes TLSv1(.0) and TLSv1.1 because [RFC8996](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8996). I believe some paid updates of j7 have both enabled 1.1 and 1.2 and then made the same changes as j8, but I don't track them.

Comment: I was using the Spring Resttemplate and as its using HttpsURLConnection to make the connections. simply setting https.cipherSuites with the missing cypher suits fixed the issue. Thanks hips.

Comment: @Reza - I am also facing same error which you got. The SSL / TLS handshake between a "Java 1.7.0_55(32-bit) TLS 1.1 client"(window machine) and a "Java 1.8 server"(unix) fails in my environment with the same exception on the client side which you got. I have installed the "JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" but still I am getting the same error. Could you please help me to, how to find out missing cipher suits ?

Comment: @KannanArumugam: it may be the same symptom (handshake_failure) but unlikely due to ciphersuites unless your server is very strict (like Reza's was). If the server is 8u291 up, that rejects 1.1 and 1.0 (as well as SSL3). OTOH j7 implements but default-excludes both 1.1 and 1.2; if your client goes to the trouble of adding 1.1 which method does it use and why doesn't it also add 1.2, which could work even with current 8? Unlimited-policy probably isn't needed on j7; AES128 works on both j7 and j8 without it -- and on 8u161 up unlimited policy is already installed OOTB. ....

Comment: ... It's unlikely this can be resolved in comments, which are limited in size and formatting, and frequently deleted; you should probably post a new Q with the full details of _your_ problem.