# Enable ciphersuite

Tags: java, x509certificate

I have to connect to a system that only accepts these ciphersuites:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

But I get a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`, because none of them are accepted by my JDK 1.7 (jdk1.7.0_80). Note that I cannot update the JDK because that version is required by the software that makes the calls. The ciphersuites [are actually valid in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html).

- I have installed [Java crypto extensions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)
- I [have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378970/jdk7-ssl-conenction-issue-ignoring-unsupported-cipher-suite-tls-ecdhe-rsa-with) unsuccessfully using the option `https.cipherSuites`

**So how can I "activate" one of the required ciphersuites?**

---

My `ClientHello` says:

```
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
 SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
 TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
 TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
 SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
 SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
 SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
 SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,
 TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
```

Comment: Please confirm that besides setting `https.cipherSuites`, you also tried setting `https.protocols=TLSv1.2`  like clearly stated  in the question AND answer you referred to in your post, but not mentioned in your Q

Comment: Yes, I set both `https.protocols` and `https.cipherSuites` as in the answer, but I think I am making some mistake because it seems ignored by looking at my `ClientHello`. I will have to investigate further....

Comment: In the answer there is also more debug info... What does yours say? Is it actualy trying to do TLS 1.2? And very, very often, software developed for 1.7 also runs on 1.8, try...

Comment: I could not make it work with 1.7 so the only solution was to get a new version using 1.8. Bad enough